# Matlab im2double normalization inconsistencness?

Tags: image, matlab

Can you explain the inconsisent behaviour of matlab `im2double` function?
Basically this function given as input a matrix A of int it normalizes the values in the range 0...1:

Example:

```
I1 = reshape(uint8(linspace(1,255,9)),[3 3])
I2 = im2double(I1)

I1 =

    1   96  192
   33  128  223
   65  160  255


I2 =

    0.0039    0.3765    0.7529
    0.1294    0.5020    0.8745
    0.2549    0.6275    1.0000
```

But now If i provide a matrix of **double**:

```
I1 =

    0.1000    0.2000
    1.5000    2.2000
```

The result of `im2double` is the same matrix I1 (so without any normalization). Can I understand this inconsisent behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `help im2double`. The first few lines are

> IM2DOUBLE takes an image as input, and returns an image of class
>   double.  If
>       the input image is of class double, the output image is identical to it.  If
>       the input image is not double, IM2DOUBLE returns the equivalent image of
>       class double, rescaling or offsetting the data as necessary.

So the behavior is intended. Indeed, when opening `im2double.m` in the editor, you'll see

```
function d = im2double(img, typestr)
...
if isa(img, 'double')
    d = img;
...

end
```

Whether it is *intuitive*, well, that's debatable :)

Anyway, there's a good reason for this behavior. With inputs of type `int8` you know what the ceiling is (`255`). With that information you can re-scale the output (`values/255`). Similar for int16 (`values/65535`), etc.

However, when you're given a `double`, you don't have a realistic ceiling anymore. For most `double` values, `values/realmax << realmin`, so there's little sense in re-scaling.

You could argue that `255` would be a good default to scale to, with a warning saying that if 16-bit data is intended, you should give an extra argument or so. But well...that gets ugly and makes the function needlessly complicated. I for one can understand Mathworks' decision to keep the original in such events.

Comment: I of course knew the documentation... I was struggling to understand the reason of this inconsistencness

Comment: @llnk: Well, with `int8` or so you know what the ceiling is (`255`), so you can scale the output image to this ceiling (`values/255`). Similar for `int16` (`values/65535`). However, when you're given a `double`, you can hardly output `values/1.7976931348623157e308` now can you? :)

Comment: @Rody: I don't think that the fact that you can hardly output that number, is a good reaon

Comment: @llnk: Really? In your second `I2`, take the maximum value (`2.2`). Now, `2.2/realmax < realmin`. Seems like a good enough reason to me.

Comment: Ok now that `< realmin` makes much more sense

Answer (score 4):

The image processing toolbox supports *two* different representations of images. Images may be stored as integer RGB values (usually 8 bit 0..255 values). *Or* they may be stored as real numbers in the range 0..1.

`im2double` ensures you have the 2nd type of representation -- in case you want to treat the image as a real array and perform various mathematical operations on it.

So if the image is already of type `double` it has its values in the range 0..1 and no need to do anything. If its not, then the function converts the input to real and rescales it by multiplying by 1/255.

Comment: Why do you say that if image is `double` its already in 0..1? I have image double where a pixel value can be `1.31234`

Comment: @llnk: Because that's Matlab's convention. Of course you can multiply the matrix by any factor you want. But, for example, imshow() uses "1.0" as the highest intensity (white). [I'm aware that you can change that behavior]